# Node JS - Express - How do i search the mongoDB object_id within the local host browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

How would i search the object_id in my browser? Any ideas? Ive tried localhost:3000/objectsearch?objectid=58499f5ed0055acc431a99f0 
but that just brings up "Please enter an objectID number and doesnt redirect me" to view.
If anyone sees the solution let me know, thanks

```
   **objectSearch.js**

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var objectID = require('mongodb')
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/WishList';



router.get('/', function (req, res) { //http://localhost:3000/objectSearch
    var _id = req.query.objectId;

    if (!_id || !parseInt(_id)) {
        res.render('error', {message: "Please enter an Buyer Identification Number", error: {status: "", stack: ""}});
    } else {
        mongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                res.render('error', {message: "Failed to connect", error: {status: "", stack: ""}});
            } else {
                var WishListDB = db.collection('orders');
                WishListDB.find({_id: mongodb.ObjectID(_id)}).toArray(function (err, result) {
                    if (err || !result || result.length == 0) {
                        res.render('error', {
                            message: "No order found with that ID number",
                            error: {status: "", stack: ""}
                        });
                    } else {
                        res.render('objectSearch', {
                            objectSearch: result[0],
                            title: result[0]
                        })
                    }

                });

            }

        })
    }

});

module.exports = router;



**objectSeach.ejs**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%=objectSearch.name.f %></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have a typo in `objectid` where you are passing `objectid=58499f5ed0055acc431a99f0` in your browser, but in your router is expecting `req.query.objectId`,

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: The `i` letter of your `objectid` query string is lower case, but your router is expecting `objectId`, you can either change `req.query.objectId` in your router to `req.query.objectid` or change the query string of `objectid` in your browser to `objectId`

Comment: alpha post an answer so i can give it as answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `i` letter of your `objectid` query string is lower case, but your router is expecting `objectId`, you can either change `req.query.objectId` in your router to `req.query.objectid` or change the query string of `objectid` in your browser to `objectId`